# Refused to load favicon.ico' it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "img-src data:

Tags: reactjs, github, favicon

I'm attempting to deploy my react.js application on Github pages, but I'm running into an issue I can't resolve.

After running npm run deploy, the page will appear correctly on the GitHub pages link but only for a few minutes. Eventually, it will report "There isn't a GitHub Pages site here.

When I check my console, it states :

"Refused to load the image "https://tandemungwa.github.io/favicon.ico" because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "img-src data:"

I've researched this problem extensively but can't find a solution. I went into index.html and changed :

to

.. also trying "shortcut icon" but that didn't work.

I've tried deleting the favicon manually from the app folder but that didn't work.

Also, when I run "npm start", despite all this, the same react favicon pops up on the tab, so it seems like the app is forcing itself to use that favicon but  I don't know how or why.

I'm quite frustrated at this point and a solution would be nice.

Thanks

Also, I'm not sure this is related but my API key is exposed in the application. I know this isn't safe but this isn't meant to be released to the general public. For this reason I've been setting the github repo to private.

Can anyone help me here?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error message in my angular 8 project,
"Refused to load the image "https://.github.io/favicon.ico" because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "img-src data:"

The problem was that the image path was incorrect,

so instead of => `<img [src]='assets/img/myImge' alt=''>`

do => `<img [src]='./assets/img/myImage'>`

also I renamed the image from *.jpg to *.JPG

everything worked fine after that.

hope that helped :)

Answer (score 0):

I just had a similar problem. In my case, the problem was with the React router package.

If you are using that package this could help.

The way I solved it was to replace the `<Router>` component of that package with `<HashRouter>`